# Why is Docker best practice to minimise the number of layers in an image?

Tags: docker, containers, images

I see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oO8n3y23b6M#t=9m10s) that

> Docker best practices says .. minimise the number of layers in our images

The tips given are to chain multiple lines in the dockerfile with `\` so as to combine many lines of code into single commands. A specific example being:

Acceptable:

```
RUN pip install jupyter

RUN pip install pandas
```

Better:

```
RUN pip install jupyter && \
pip install pandas
```

From this knowledge, I understand what should be done, however, I don't understand why. What are the advantages of minimising the number of layers in a Docker image? (or, conversely, what are the *dis*advantages of *not* doing so?)

Comment: Best is:
 RUN pip install jupyter pandas ))

Comment: Note that there is a typo in your last example - that second `RUN` shouldn't be there.

Comment: @AndreiMustață thanks for picking up on that! - fixed

Answer (score 4):

you should minimize the Layers of an Image for following Reasons:

- first, you can only have (afaik) 127 Layers in an Image.
- second: yes, you should include severals Steps in a Single run because of the Copy-On-Write functionality:

if you run:

```
RUN dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat  bs=1M  count=10
RUN rm -rf output.dat
```

your image is still 10MB (plus some bytes for the delete Marker)

instead, you should run:

```
RUN dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat  bs=1M  count=10 &&\
    rm -rf output.dat
```

then, your image size is not increasing.

surely, this is not the Usual Use-Case, but, for example from a Real-World-Example:

```
# install terraform
ENV TF_VERSION="0.12.16"
RUN curl -LO https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TF_VERSION}/terraform_${TF_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip \
  && unzip terraform_${TF_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip \
  && chmod +x ./terraform \
  && mv ./terraform /usr/local/bin/terraform \
  && rm terraform_${TF_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip
```

more informations here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#the-copy-on-write-cow-strategy